# Исчезает обращение к пользователю из комментариев к вопросам/ответам

Tags: дефект

Столкнулся с проблемой при комментировании вопросов и ответов.
Пишу с двух компов, дома Win7, на работе Ubuntu 14.04.

Когда пытаюсь вставить метку пользователя, которому отвечаю (@nickname), то дома не вставляются ники на латинице, а на работе - ники на кириллице.
Когда пишу ник вручную, в комментарии он просто исчезает.

С чем может быть связана эта проблема?

Comment: О последнем: весьма вероятно, что вы отвечали в комментарии автору поста: в этом случае особое обращение необязательно, автор и так получит уведомление, а явное упоминание автора в начале комментария при этом может стереться.

Comment: Браузеры одинаковые?